# How to write a literal dot in ed?

Tags: editors, ed

What would be the right way to write a line containing only `.` to a file in `ed`?
The only way I came up with is something like this:

```
a
.
s/^$/./
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the no shell way,

```
a
a.
.
s/a//
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit round about, but use shell redirection:

```
r !echo .
```